# call middleware function in router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchdb, middleware

I'm implementing sessions on my express.js app with [Mozilla’s client-sessions](https://github.com/mozilla/node-client-sessions) and I need some help. I have my post and gest request in my router.js and the middleware in app.js, I get this error when I run it :

> ReferenceError: requireLogin is not defined

//index.js (router)

```js
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()
  , user = require('../public/js/models/test.js');



router.get('/profile-header', requireLogin, function (req, res, html) {
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render('templates/profile-header.jade', { title: 'Default' })
});


router.get('/sign-in', function (req, res, html) {
  res.render('templates/sign-in.jade', { title: 'Sign In' })
});


router.get('/blog-home', requireLogin, function (req, res, html) {
  res.render('templates/blog-home.jade', { title: 'Blog' })
});


router.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.session.reset();
  res.redirect('/');
});


router.post('/profile-header', function (req, res, html) {
  user.login(req.body,  function (e, o) {
    if (o) {
      //add session
      req.session.user = o;
      res.redirect('/profile-header');
    } else {
      res.render('templates/sign-in.jade', { error: 'Invalid email or password.' });
    }
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

//app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
var should = require('should');
var session = require('client-sessions');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
function requireLogin (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.user) {
    console.log("pd");
    res.redirect('/sign-in');
  } else {
    next();
  }
};


app.use(session({
  cookieName: 'session',
  secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
  duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
  activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(stylus.middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session && req.session.user) {
     user.exist(req.session.username, function  (e, o) {
      if (user) {
        req.user = user;
        delete req.user.user_password; // delete the password from the session
        req.session.user = user;  //refresh the session value
        console.log(req.session);
        res.locals.user = user;
      }
      // finishing processing the middleware and run the route
      next();
    });
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
// listener
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
 console.log('Listening on http://localhost:' + (process.env.PORT || 3000))
})

module.exports = app;
```

Thx for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `requireLogin` is defined in `app.js`, but in `index.js` it's not defined.
I'd suggest to move `requireLogin` in an external service and import/require it when needed:

```
// auth.service.js
exports.requireLogin = function (req, res, next) { ... };
```

Then in `index.js` add this:

```
var Auth = require('./auth.service');

....

router.get('/profile-header', Auth.requireLogin, function (req, res, html) {
  console.log(req.session);
  res.render('templates/profile-header.jade', { title: 'Default' })
});
```

Comment: Ok thx, I don't need to call it in app.js tho ? The only time it was working properly was when the function and all the get / post were in the app.js

Comment: As I see from you code you don't call it in `app.js`. It's just declared there. So if you move it to external service you can remove it from `app.js`.

Comment: Ok, I still got a problem, when I sign up my request goes fine and I get my user info, but then its redirected on the login page by requireLogin ( not the one its supposed too if the login is successfull), I can't figure out why.. Thanks a lot for helping me !

Comment: It redirects if there is no user attached to `req` object. Maybe you don't add `user` to `req` after login?

Comment: There is a condition `if (user)`. Maybe it can't find user and thus do not add it to `req`.

Comment: Even when I put `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 console.log(req.session.username)};` in the app.use it doesn't do anything..

Comment: If it doesn't print username then it means that for some reasons you don't have it stored in session.

Comment: I can't find why, I do it in `router.post('/profile', function (req, res, html)` ....... `req.session.user = o;`, thx again !